# closing a pipe and duplicating a pipe

Tags: c, linux, pipe, dup

I'm trying to understand how pipes work and it is rather confusing when I was reading this code in my textbook. In the line

```
dup(fd2[0]); close(fd2[0]);
```

why are we duplicating `fd2[0]`,then close it right after we duplicated it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  struct timespec ts1, ts2;
  pid_t newpid;
  int fd1[2], fd2[2];
  char m0[] = "\nabout to fork....\n";
  char m1[] = "message from parent to child\n";
  char m2[] = "message from child to parent\n";
  char m3[] = "\ndone....\n";
  char rbuf1[256];
  char rbuf2[256];
  int cn1, cn2;
  ts1.tv_sec=(time_t)1;
  ts1.tv_nsec=(long)1;
  ts2.tv_sec=(time_t)1;
  ts2.tv_nsec=(long)1;
  if ((pipe(fd1)==-1)) printf("error\n");
  if ((pipe(fd2)==-1)) printf("error\n");
  printf("fd1 %d %d fd2 %d %d\n", fd1[0], fd1[1], fd2[0], fd2[1]);

  if ((newpid=fork()) ==-1) {
    printf("failed to fork\n\n");
    return 0;
  }

  if (newpid > 0) { // parent ***************
    close(fd1[1]); close(fd2[0]); // closing 4 and 5
    dup(fd2[1]); close(fd2[1]); // taking 4 in place of 6
    write(4, m1, sizeof(m1)); // parent_to_child messg
    usleep(10000);
    cn1=read(3, rbuf1, 256);
    write(1, rbuf1, cn1);
  } else { // child ***************
    close(fd1[0]); close(fd2[1]); // closing 3 and 6
    dup(fd2[0]); close(fd2[0]); // taking 3 in place of 5
    write(4, m2, sizeof(m2)); // child_to_parent messg
    usleep(10000);
    cn2=read(3, rbuf2, 256);
    write(1, rbuf2, cn2);
  }
  write(2, m3, sizeof(m3));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you have there seems to have nothing to do with your question. I can't see a "dup" anywhere.

Comment: sorry, I forget to add the second half of the code in my question

Comment: please format the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show us your code, however, from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) of `dup()`

```
int dup(int oldfd);
```

and

```
dup() uses the lowest-numbered unused descriptor for the new descriptor.
```

This clearly says, `dup()` will return a new file descriptor for `oldfd`. you need to assign the return value of `dup()` to get the new `fd`. Once you get the new `fd`, you can close the old `fd` and use the newly returned descriptor to access the file.

Once more approach, commonly used, is to close a well-known file descriptor and after that call `dup()` which will assign the recently closed `fd` as the new `fd`. [Example : `STDIN_FILENO`]

Comment: Is that means whenever I call close(fd), it will close the old fd and never the new fd?

Comment: @Learning yes, provided you're supplying the old `fd` to `close()`. the return value will give you the new `fd`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual sequence is to have another `close` call before the `dup` call, or to assign the result of the `dup` and use it.

The first variant is the most common, for example to use the pipe read end as the new `STDIN_FILENO` you can do

```
close(STDIN_FILENO);  // Close the current standard input descriptor
dup(pipefds[0]);      // Duplicate the pipe read-end, which will become our new standard input
close(pipefds[0);     // Close the old pipe descriptor, to save descriptor resources
```

This will work because `dup` will select the *lowest* available descriptor, which after the first `close` call will be `STDIN_FILENNO` (descriptor `0`).

And `dup` does exactly what it souds like, it *duplicates* the descriptor, so after a call to `dup` you will have two descriptors referencing the same "file", and can freely close one of them.

I suggest you read the [the `dup(2)` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html).